# UITest cannot find element when contained in Modal View Controller

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing, ios-ui-automation, xcode10

I have an application that has the following structure:

- A root UIViewController (A).
- Inside it is a UINavigationController (B) that pushes and pops different UIViewControllers (C).
- Sometimes, the UIViewControllers (C) inside the UINavigationController (B) will present Modal UIViewControllers (D).

When trying to record a UITest elements inside A, B and C are detected. But any elements inside the Modal UIViewControllers D are not found. I just get stuck until I get an error that looks like this:

**Timeout waiting for fulfillment of promise for 'remote query'.**

All elements have accessibility identifiers.

Any ideas?